# Query in PostgreSQL became slow and then got better on its own - why?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-10, postgresql-performance

I want to better understand how to debug and fix performance issues in PostgreSQL.

I have a query that usually costs 1 second to run. However, for some reason, it started taking 30 seconds to run for a period of time! After some minutes and some *explain analyze* invocations, it went back to normal. I didn't do anything to fix it, nor did I understand why it got better all of a sudden.

How do I debug a problem like this? What kind of logging and instrumentation should I have in place to understand what caused this and how to fix it?

Comment: System busy overall? Table(s) undergoing a large update? Large analytic type query being run?  The Gods not appreciating your invocations? :-)  On a more serious note, this is the reason you should have monitoring software installed **before** problems arise! Do you have anything like sysstat or nagios or similar?

Comment: No. Just some simple logs in pg. Was considering using the ELK stack to get all kinds of verbose logs

Comment: Have you considered the excellent (and Open Source) sysstat tools?

Comment: Go this link. It may help you..! https://www.dbrnd.com/2016/02/postgresql-important-parameters-for-better-performance/

Answer (score 2):

It is a very broad question, even more so as you give absolutely no details about your setup and kind of database (volume, type of queries, active connections, size of RAM, dedicated server or not, etc.)

You can start by enabling PostgreSQL to log slow queries, see the `log_min_duration_statement` in the configuration. That will give you historical data that you would then be able to analyze and maybe correlate with other things (like from the list of @Vérace)

You will then have various tools to help, as described on https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Logging_Difficult_Queries :

- pgFouine
- PQA
- EPQA
- pgsi